# Wordpress SSL not working on all pages

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl

I have installed the plugins `WordPress HTTPS`, and updated the `Wordpress Address` and `Site Address` to use `https`. The site works fine and all the pages are working in `https`, but when I check the sitemap (by Jetpack) only the homepage link shows with `https` the other links are `http`. Is there something that I forgot to update?